# Is $\sup\left\{\sum_{a∈F}|f(a)|:F\text{ is finite subset of }A\right\}<∞$ the same as $\sum_{a∈A}|f(a)| < ∞?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:A→\mathbb{R}$

Can we say that: $$\sup\left\{\sum_{a∈F}|f(a)|:F\text{ is finite subset of }A\right\}<∞$$ is equivalent to: $$\sum_{a∈A}|f(a)| < ∞?$$

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, if $A$ is countable:

If $\sum_{a∈A}|f(a)| = ∞$ we can take increasing finite subsets $\lbrace a_1\rbrace\subset \lbrace a_1,a_2\rbrace\subset\ldots\subset A$ to get $\sup\left\{\sum_{a∈F}|f(a)|:F\text{ is finite subset of }A\right\}=∞$, since the sequence $\left(\sum_{a\in A_i}\vert f(a)\vert\right)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\sum_{a\in A}\vert f(a)\vert$.

By $\sup\left\{\sum_{a∈F}|f(a)|:F\text{ is finite subset of }A\right\}\leq \sum_{a∈A}|f(a)| $ we get the other direction.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand. could you explain this matter in detail?

Comment: Maybe I was too fast: Which kind of set is $A$? Is it countable? If not, what do you mean by $\sum_{a∈A}|f(a)|$?

Comment: @mathmax This is just a guess but it seems another account is also owned by this person and that account asked this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780850/exercise-on-measure-theory/782270 in which the definition of the sum occurs.

Comment: @user10444: if the definition given there is the correct one, I don't know what to show.

Comment: This is correct for arbitrary cardinality of $A$.