# show that sum of $f(x)$ which $x$ is in $X$ is same to sup{sum of $f(x)$ which $x$ is in $F$ is finite subset of $X$}

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

in this question [Exercise on measure theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780850/exercise-on-measure-theory)

how can we say that 
$$\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \sup\left\{\sum_{x∈F}f(x),\ F\subseteq X,\ F\ \text{finite} \right \}$$?

left side is sum of all element in $X$ and right side is at most $\sup\{\text{only small part of}\  X\}$

show that this equation.

Comment: It's a definition! The left-hand side is only defined in general when $X$ is finite or countable (because in your exercise we assume $f(x) \ge 0$). Therefore if $X$ is an arbitrary set we need to make a definition, which is this one.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick is right.  For instance, suppose that $X$ is the set of integers and $f(x)=1/(x^2+1)$.  Then

$$\sum_{x=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1} = \sup_n \sum_{x=-n}^n \frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$